# CSS - Div does not follow animated parent element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have a block of text overlay an animated (keyframed) image.

So far, I have tried combinations of display attributes such as inline-block with no luck. I have also attempted to play around with the positions, setting both the heading and the image to relative and absolute.

I would like the heading text (h4) to follow the animated image behind it.

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

h4 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 128px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.transactionBG {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.transaction {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  position: absolute;
  animation: upDown 1.5s alternate infinite ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes upDown {
  to {
    transform: translateY(100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="transactionBG" style="top: 10%;left: 50%;width: 128px;height: 278px;">
  <img class="transaction" src="https://seeklogo.com/images/I/instagram-circle-logo-E285122AB7-seeklogo.com.png" style="width: 102.4px; height: 102.4px;">
  <h4>test</h4>
</div>
```

Current State Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4huj31fb/2/

Comment: you are not animating parent, you are animating only the image, if you want to animate both then you have either add 2 different animation or animate the div that contains it. In your case the parent is transactionBG not transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you gave the animation to the image only. move this line :

```
animation: upDown 1.5s alternate infinite ease-in-out;
```

to the **.transactionBG** selector

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

h4 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 128px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.transactionBG {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: upDown 1.5s alternate infinite ease-in-out;
}

.transaction {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes upDown {
  to {
    transform: translateY(100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="transactionBG" style="top: 10%;left: 50%;width: 128px;height: 278px;">
  <img class="transaction" src="https://seeklogo.com/images/I/instagram-circle-logo-E285122AB7-seeklogo.com.png" style="width: 102.4px; height: 102.4px;">
  <h4>test</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`transactionBG` is the parent of h4. So you have to add the animation to `transactionBG`

```
.transactionBG {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: upDown 1.5s alternate infinite ease-in-out;
}
```